# Application Delegate Usage

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates

I'm fairly new to Objective-C and cocoa programming, so I don't really understand the concept of App Delegates.

When we create a cocoa application, do we store our code (Methods, actions, outlets) in the App Delegate files or do we create a new file that will act as a controller and code from there. Right now, I put all of my code in those two files, but from what I read, your goal is to try to make your App Delegate files as slim as possible.

My question is: What's the usage of the app delegate files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talking about `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`:
It's just your application entry point. Normally you only create the window and your first ViewController, or your Tabbar - your main starting interface class - here.

All the other delegate methods of the `NSApplicationDelegate` have other functions of course. Most of them are the point, where you react on the state of the app. Opened / Closed / Backgrounded / Reopened etc.

But you should probably have a look at the programming tutorials in the iPhone documentation. There is a lot of information on how to structure your objc projects. E.g. look here: [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Or if your looking for OSX Apps, look here:

1) [Your First Mac App](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Mac101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010611)
2) [Mac App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543)

There is also a bunch of [Sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code).

Comment: Do you have any documentation for Desktop Applications (Not iphone)?

Answer (score 1):

The App Delegate is a handler location to handle events that occur on the application. Things like open and close. It also hangs around the whole time the application is executing and you can grab the singleton instance at any point by doing `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`.

This comes in handy for handing objects between controllers and serving as a router for events. You can also store some data on the delegate if you need to modify/have access to it in different parts of the code.

This all works well for simple applications, but as things become more complex, you need to have some division of responsibilities. The AppDelegate should really only be responsible for actions that occur on the application itself, not on another view or a controller. Putting all/most of your code in the AppDeligate is certainly bad practice and will lead to horrible code as things get more complex and need to be maintained.